# Validate a query string?

Tags: php, regex, string, validation

```
first=value
first=value&arr[]=foo+bar&arr[]=baz
```

How can I use PHP to validate a query string, which is a sequence of

```
[name]=[value]&
```

Comment: "Validate" what exactly?

Comment: Please explain, what validate means. Do you need to check, that certain parameters get passed? Or do you want to check their values?

Comment: Sorry, I just need to check that the query string is in its proper form

`[name]=[value]&`

(With or without &)

Comment: The problem is that pretty much *anything* can be a query string. There's very little that would constitute an *invalid* query string. Are you saying you *require* that each `name` has a `value`? Because `foo&bar` is a perfectly valid query string, too...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't say I understand what you are asking, but if we are talking about the specific value above:

```
$value = $_GET['first']; //value
$arr = isset($_GET['arr']) ? $_GET['arr'] : null; //array('foo bar', 'baz')
```

If you are asking if you can validate whether a query string is in a usable format .. well you can't, really.  There is large variety of possible query strings and you can really put in whatever you want.  It is up to you to check if the values you are expecting are set and checking whether the data in them is usable for your purposes.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['name'])) {
        $name = $_GET['name'];
        if ($name == 'value') {...};
}
if (!isset($_GET['arr'])) {
      echo "URL is not in correct format!";
      exit;
}
?>
```